# Where does ParseFile.getDataInBackground() store data?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Does it store the data in memory or in the disk?

Asked this because I am planning to convert my parse file into an image thumbnail in which i set it to my list items. If it's in memory there would be no need to decode it in a background thread and since the file is in memory it would be garbage collected say when the activity is closed right?

```
ParseFile imageFile = event.getThumbnailFile();
final ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_thumbnail);
imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_report_problem_black_48dp));

imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); // will replace this to convert bigger images into small ones
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if the `getDataInBackground` is successful it apparently stores the the ParseFile in a disk cache. Subsequent calls to the method updates the disk cache when the file is updated on the cloud.